# Python/BeautifulSoup: Scrape Data from Web Pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python programming, and I am trying to learn how to scrape web pages. What I'm trying to do is to  scrape data from this [web page](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149)

I am trying to scrape the `ISSUE DATE` from the above page (You can see the `ISSUE DATE` if you open the web page). I am facing some problem with this.

This is the code I wrote for this.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149"

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
value1 = soup.findAll('TABLE')

for value in value1:
    date1 = value.find('B').text
    print date1
```

Comment: case of the tag shouldn't matter but the documentation has lower case tag names not uppercase http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs%29

Comment: ya i need to scrape out the "Issue date" from the web page

Comment: I am unable to print the Issue date. I don't know where i am going wrong.I am new to python programming please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If, before the loop, you add ... `print value1`
you can see that the html has an error on line 37 at character 27, which is a closing double quote that is missing its opening double quote.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not optimized, but here's one way of getting back the issue date:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149"

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
issue_date = soup.findAll('b')[5].text
print issue_date
```

Comment: the out put of this code is coming out as none. i am not getting the date.Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup needs the tag names to be in lower case.  Note, also, that using a few
try.. except blocks would make debugging this a bit easier.  The following code seems
to achieve what you want:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149"

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
value1 = soup.findAll('table')
n=0
for value in value1:
    date1 = value.find('b')
    try: print n,date1.text
    except: print n
    n=n+1
try: print "The winner is:",value1[3].find('b').text
except: pass
```

Comment: i am unable to print the date.its showing 'NONE'. can you please help me.

Comment: The out put of the Code is coming out as none. i am unable to print the Issue date.Can you please help me.

Comment: Add this line at the end: `code` print "The winner is:",value1[3].find('tr').findAll('td')[-1].text

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is the same accross the pages you can do this

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149"

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
for td in soup.findAll('td'):
    if td.get('width','') !='' and td.get('width')=='80%':
        print td.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **find** text function then iterate to next element with **next** function like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
url="http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=0000149.PN.&OS=PN/0000149&RS=PN/0000149"
html=requests.get(url).content
issue_date_zone = BeautifulSoup(html).find(text='Issue Date:')
date_str=issue_date_zone.next.next.text
print date_str
```

result is:

```
March 25, 1837
```